# Split/group collectible by consecutive elements

Tags: kotlin

Suppose I have a list/array containing chars. How do I group/split/join them so that I get something like this?

```
val input = arrayOf('b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e')

val output = groupOrSplit(input) // ['bb', 'c', 'd', 'eee']
```

Comment: For an array `['b', 'c', 'b']`, what is your expected result? `['bb', 'c']` or `['b', 'c', 'b']`?

Comment: Looking for ['b', 'c', 'b'] there, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There are no functions to split string like you want in standard library, so you have to write this function by yourself:

```
fun splitDistinct(arr: CharArray): List<String> = arr
    .fold(ArrayList<StringBuilder>()) { acc, ch -> acc.apply {
        if (isEmpty() || last().last() != ch)
            add(StringBuilder(ch.toString()))
        else
            last().append(ch)
    }}
    .map { it.toString() }


fun main() {
    val arr = charArrayOf('b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'e', 'e')
    println(splitDistinct(arr))
}
```

Comment: Thank you, appreciate that. Still learning and it's not always clear whether there's a hidden amazing method to do these things or not.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, then I would do something like this:

```
listOf("b", "b", "c", "d", "e", "e", "e").asSequence()

    // b => b to ["b", "b"]
    // c => c to ["c"], etc
    .groupBy { it }

    // b => "bb", etc
    .map { entry -> entry.value.joinToString("") }

    .toList()

// Result is listOf("bb", "c", "d", "eee")
```